# Installing Ubuntu12.04 64-bit on VMware

Tags: vmware

While installing Ubuntu 12.04 desktop on VMware Workstation it hangs when reticulating splines. How long do I have to wait?

Comment: Doesn't your ISO got recognized and 'Easy Installed'?

Answer (score 0):

From reading [this ubuntuforums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2171525) and my own experience, I believe you can safely restart the system at this point without ill effects.